# needleman wunsh loop not terminating matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, bioinformatics

I am trying to implement needleman wunsh algorithm as a function in matlab. The function works correctly for sequences of the same size but for different sizes, it expands score matrix to which ever of the two sequences is of highest length.
Can someone tell me why this is happening? Thanks.

```
function [ mat, direction ] = build_score_mat( seq1, seq2 )
%BUILD_SCORE_MAT Takes two sequences and builds a score matrix for global
%alignment
m = length(seq1);
n = length(seq2);
mat = zeros(m+2,n+2);
dir_mat = zeros(m+2,n+2);
direction = zeros(m+2,n+2);
mat(1,3:m+2) = seq1;
mat(3:n+2,1) = seq2;
mat(2,3:m+2) = -2:-2:-2*m;
mat(3:n+2,2) = -2:-2:-2*n;
for i=3:m+2    
    for j=3:n+2
        if(mat(i,1) == mat(1,j))
            score = 5; %diagnol align
        else
            score = -1;
        end
        list = [mat(i-1,j-1)+score, mat(i,j-1)-2, mat(i-1,j)-2];
        [mat(i,j), dir_mat(i,j)]= max(list);
        direction(i,j) = dir_mat(i,j);
    end
end


end
```

Comment: Can you explain what are the inputs `seq1` and `seq2` and the outputs `mat`, `direction`? Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand how would you use this function.

Comment: seq1 and seq2 are strings to be aligned. mat is the output matrix after alignment and direction is the direction matrix for the traceback to get the output aligned words/sequences which will be done using another function that takes these as the input.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of came up with a workaround myself by adding another matrix that copies the score matrix. The function works perfectly now.

```
function [ matRet, direction ] = build_score_mat( seq1, seq2 )
%BUILD_SCORE_MAT Takes two sequences and builds a score matrix for global
%alignment
m = length(seq1);
n = length(seq2);
mat = zeros(m+2,n+2);
matRet = zeros(m+2,n+2);
dir_mat = zeros(m+2,n+2);
direction = zeros(m+2,n+2);
mat(1,3:m+2) = seq1;
mat(3:n+2,1) = seq2;
mat(2,3:m+2) = -2:-2:-2*m;
mat(3:n+2,2) = -2:-2:-2*n;
for i=3:m+2    
    for j=3:n+2
        if(mat(i,1) == mat(1,j))
            score = 5; %diagnol align
        else
            score = -1;
        end
        list = [mat(i-1,j-1)+score, mat(i,j-1)-2, mat(i-1,j)-2];
        [mat(i,j), dir_mat(i,j)]= max(list);
        matRet(i,j) = mat(i,j);
        direction(i,j) = dir_mat(i,j);
    end
end


end
```